# Calculate number of item over and under threshold

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, hana

I'm trying to find out the "fastest" number of items above 80 % (threshold) of total sales in a category and also the number of items below 80 % (threshold) of total sales in a category.

Below is the raw data set.

```
Category    Items   Sales
0001        1000    400
0001        1001    100
0001        1002    13
0001        1003    300
0001        1004    10
0001        1005    11
0001        1006    12
0001        1007    200
0001        1008    14
0001        1009    15
```

Above 80% (threshold) of Total sales (860).

```
Category     Number of item *above threshold
0001         3
```

For category 0001, "fastest" number of items hitting 80 % threshold is 3, namely 1000, 1003, 1007 with total of 900 (400 + 300 + 200).

Below 80% (threshold) of Total sales (860).

```
Category     Number of item *below threshold
0001         7
```

For category 0001, the number of items below 80 % threshold is 7, namely 1001, 1002, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1008, 1009.

I am not sure this is achievable by set-based solution, these seen like it will requires iteration to find number of items for fastest over and below 80 % threshold of sales.

I could find out the total sales for category and therefore 80 % of the total sales but I am having difficulty to find out  "fastest" number of items above 80 % (threshold) of total sales in a category. Anyone have any idea how to do so?

Please let me know if you need more details.

Regards,
Mike

Comment: you should pick one database. a solution for mysql will differ from a solution for another db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution which should work on almost any DMBS (tested on MySQL and Oracle, also works for PostgreSQL, SQL Server and SQLite, but you have to take care that you are not using integer division there [could multiply cumulative sales by 1.0 to make it really run on all of them]):

```
SELECT
   O.Category,
   SUM(CASE WHEN O.CumulativeSales / O.TotalSales < 1 - Thresh THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) Above,
   SUM(CASE WHEN O.CumulativeSales / O.TotalSales < 1 - Thresh THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Under
FROM
   (SELECT
      T.Category,
      (SELECT
         SUM(Sales)
      FROM
         ...
      WHERE
         Sales <= T.Sales AND Category = T.Category
      ) AS CumulativeSales,
      (SELECT
         SUM(Sales)
      FROM
         ...
      WHERE
         Category = T.Category
      ) AS TotalSales
   FROM
      ... T
   ) O
GROUP BY
   O.Category
;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server 2012+:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8ffb2/1/0)

```
DECLARE @treshold NUMERIC(5, 2) = 0.80;

WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        ss = SUM(Sales) OVER(PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY Sales DESC)
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT
    c.Category,
    above = n,
    below = c.cnt - n
FROM(
    SELECT 
        Category, 
        cnt = COUNT(*),
        tresh = @treshold * SUM(Sales)
    FROM tbl GROUP BY Category
)c
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT 
        n = COUNT(*)
    FROM Tbl
    WHERE Category = c.Category
    AND Sales >= (SELECT TOP 1 Sales FROM Cte WHERE ss >= c.tresh)
)a
```

**RESULT**:

```
| Category | above | below |
|----------|-------|-------|
|     0001 |     3 |     7 |
```